# Angular - Autocomplete is not working well

Tags: html, angular, forms, dom-events, autofocus

I'm having a problem with `autofocus` on input of my HTML. When the page loads, my saved login shows up and the mark of focus shows up on the beginning of the input like the picture before.

[image]

But when I type something on the keyboard, the letter will be inserted on the end of the input like this:

[image]

I tried to fix it, without success. I would like to have the mark of the focus on the end of the input, or on the beginning, but working normal.

I'm using angular 11

My code:

```
<input autofocus [(ngModel)]="usuario.name" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Insira o login">
```

Comment: On focus the browser will position the cursor on the position from before the previous blur event. In case there wasn't blur event it will position the cursor after the last symbol. Check this example https://codepen.io/urak/pen/zYrVwNb

Answer (score 0):

The `autofocus` attribute is buggy. This is happening because your input value is coming after the input is focused.

You should use the `focus` function using `ViewChild` and put focus on `input` after data came. To achieve this:

```
constructor() {}

@ViewChild('myname') input: ElementRef;
...
private someFunction(): void {
  // Data is loaded using service
  this.input.nativeElement.focus(); // now focus
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but didn't work for me. The erro still happens. If I put some value on the model, it works, but because the value is from the save password, it doesn't work.

Comment: @pvfreitas Have you tried it in afterviewinit lifecycle hook?

Comment: Yes, brother. I tried with setTimeout() too. If I do like this: "this.usuario.name = 'pet';". It works. But my username came from the browser. Its saved there.

Comment: Looks like the model is not in sync with the view. I would suggest you to listen to the input event on the control and update the value with your model before programmatically focusing the input. And obviously do this only for the browser prefill and not for the user action

Answer (score 0):

I solved the situation disabling autocomplete like this:

```
<input autocomplete="new-password" [(ngModel)]="usuario.password" type="password" name="senha" id="senha" placeholder="Insira a senha">
```

Now the user needs to select the password saved. Thank you guys.